# Security in in-game NFT mint

Tags: security, blockchain, solidity, nft

does anyone know how to create a secure in-game NFT mint? I think if we gave permission to users to create an NFT (this is the idea of the game - to assemble an NFT from different parts), it would be vulnerable because you can insert your own image URL into the function. I thought a mint function that can be used only by a game contract with the `require(somePartsAmount)`, would it be **secure**?
Something like this:

```
function awardItem(address player, string memory tokenURI)
        public 
        onlyGame
        returns (uint256)
{
        require(somePartsAmount);
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(player, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
}
```

**How to be with the presale mint, because we can't check parts here and creating by owner is too expensive?**

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you won't want to give users the opportunity to set a custom token URI to an nft. Thus, I would suggest making all the URI things in another function maybe. For you to have, let's say, 1000 minteable random nfts, you would first need 1000 tokenURIs for those nfts to have information attached to, and then you would have to use the default getTokenURI function which returns the base token URI you specify when creating the smart contract and just adds the nft id to the end of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think your idea will be good at this. What do you think about signing transaction with this uri on server by owner?

Comment: Yes! You could also make it that way. But 100% of the gas fees will go to you. If you want to do it that way you could maybe add a checker to require the msg.sender to be only the owner, so that others can't call it.